# Conditional Static Resource For Itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

at the moment in order to fix a bug from telerik, my ItemsSource must be pointing to the viewmodel I'm currently working with.

Relationship.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <Client:PersonViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Where it's used.

```
 <Telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Relationship" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding GridRelationshipTypes, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}" 
                                 DataMemberBinding="{Binding RelationshipType}" 
                                 SelectedValueMemberPath="Id" 
                                 DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                                 IsReadOnly="False"/>
```

I have four other view models this logic needs to be applied to. I don't want to create 5 different UserControls for such a small thing. I'm wondering if I can create a method such that it'll check what the current viewmodel type is and will use the corresponding viewmodel.

PseudoCode - ViewModelTypes is an enum.

```
public void StaticResourcToUse(ViewModelTypes viewModelType)
{
    if (viewModelType == ViewModelTypes.PersonViewModel)
        use personviewmodel resources
    if (viewModelType == ViewModelTypes.BusinessViewModel)
        use businessViewModel resources
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want is switch your view based on view model.

Use a `ContentControl` to display the data, and swap out the `ContentTemplate` in a trigger based on the property that changes.

[Here's an example in Rachel Lim's blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) that swaps a template based on a bound property:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CarTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:YourViewModel}">
     <TextBlock Text="I'm a Car" />
</DataTemplate> 

<DataTemplate x:Key="TrackTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:YourViewModel}">
     <TextBlock Text="I'm a Track" />
 </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourViewModel}">
     <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
         <ContentControl.Style>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                 <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CarTemplate}" />
                 <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourType}" Value="Track">
                         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TrackTemplate}" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
         </ContentControl.Style>
     </ContentControl>
 </DataTemplate>
```